# temporary variable manipulation visibility in SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, select, variable-assignment

How is temporary variable manipulation defined in **MySQL**? It seems that any change of the value will be "visible" immediately after the assignment expression. If I run the query

```sql
SELECT 
  @x as x,
  @x + (@x:=@x+1) + @x as magic,
  @x as new_x
FROM 
  (SELECT @x:=0) x,
  Values1to100 numbers
```

it returns

```
+---+-------+-------+
| x | magic | new_x |
+===+=======+=======+
| 0 |     2 |     1 |
+---+-------+-------+
| 1 |     5 |     2 |
+---+-------+-------+
| 2 |     8 |     3 |
+---+-------+-------+
| ...               |
```

Now I'm wondering is this the well-defined behavior of MySQL (or SQL in general) or not (ie the result depends on the implementation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`MySQL documentation`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) says

> For statements such as SELECT, you might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. In the following statement, you might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an assignment second:

```
SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...;
```

> However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.